# Cant find interface eth0 for vrrp_instance VI_1

Tags: node.js, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-location, nginx-status

Currently, I am trying to run **KEEPALIVED** with **NGINX** on my machine. My use-case includes monitoring the failover behavior for NGINX server because any one instance can go down and I need to have other instance alive to serve the incoming request.

Below is my `keepalived.conf` file,

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
     track_script {
            chk_http_port
        }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.100.160.143
    }
}

vrrp_script chk_http_port {
        script "pidof nginx"
        interval 2

}
```

below is the error I am getting at location `/var/logs/messages`

```
Keepalived_vrrp[33045]: Cant find interface eth0 for vrrp_instance VI_1 !!!
Keepalived_vrrp[33045]:     chk_http_port no match, ignoring...
Keepalived_vrrp[33045]: Default interface eth0 does not exist and no interface specified. Skipping static address 10.100.160.143.
Keepalived_vrrp[33045]: WARNING - default user 'keepalived_script' for script execution does not exist - please create.
Keepalived_vrrp[33045]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Unknown interface !
Keepalived_vrrp[33045]: Stopped
Keepalived[33042]: Keepalived_vrrp exited with permanent error CONFIG. Terminating
Keepalived[33042]: Stopping
Keepalived_healthcheckers[33044]: Stopped
Keepalived[33042]: Stopped Keepalived v1.3.5 (03/19,2017), git commit v1.3.5-6-g6fa32f2
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to check the name of your network interface. Use **ifconfig** to list all your network interfaces, and look for 'eth0'. If 'eth0' doesn't exist on your machine, then you need to specify the name of an existing interface in your keepalived.conf